# ActiveRecord Rails 4 Chaining .select query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm trying to select from my InventoryPart db, the parts that are unique by part number and company. I've done so:

```
parts = InventoryPart.select('DISTINCT ON (part_num, company_id) *')
```

But after this I'm trying to chain on another select, so that I can get a collection of the unique part numbers that are in the previous AR Relation with:

```
parts.select("distinct part_num")
```

But all this does is return every `InventoryPart.all`

Is there no way to chain the `select` method?

Answer (score 1):

You can absolutely chain on `select`:

```
Foo.select('count(some_col) as some_col_count').select('1 as one')
```

This will return two columns with the specified info.

You're running into issues because you're trying to combine SQL literals and the AST that Arel (and subsequently, ActiveRecord) is using to assemble the SQL query. Instead you might want to try this:

```
InventoryPart.select(:part_num, :company_id).distinct
```

If you want to use `DISTINCT_ON`, you can do this:

```
table = InventoryPart.arel_table
unique_parts = InventoryPart.select(:part_num).distinct_on([table[:part_num], table[:company_id])
InventoryPart.find_by_sql(unique_parts.to_sql)
```